# JavaScript Form Submit Value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a legacy HTML form (that i dont control) that looks like this:

```
<form action="submit_action" method="get">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="textarea1"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="result" />
  <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="result" />
</form>
```

I need to read the values out of this form and do a HTTP POST to a REST API service. I wrote a function that would read out the input elements from the form and create a object from them like this:

```
const form = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = (event) => this.onFormSubmit(event);

function onFormSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();

  const action = form.attributes['action'].value;
  let result = Object.keys(form.elements).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const element = form.elements[k];
    acc[element.name] = element.value;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  console.log('Form Result', action, result);
}
```

In a classical form submit, the button that triggered the submission is passed a parameter. In this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_name.asp you see when you click the FORM it passes the button that was clicked in the post.

Is there a better way to do this so that I can read that out?

Comment: Put a handler on the submit button?

Comment: I don't control the form.

Comment: ... You didn't when you added a submit handler, either.

Comment: You are passing the event but not receiving it in the function, the event should have the target element that triggered the event.